# How to understand the following update sql statement without where

Tags: mysql

How to understand the following sql? I would think the syntax is error, but it updates the whole table and set column `progress` with value 0. The sql updates `progress` with value 0 instead of 5, but `semester_id` is not affected.
`update table set progress = 5 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4;`

This sql is handwriting error and shouldn't be executed(The first `and` should be `where`). However it was executed and all data was affected unexpectedly. Data was recovered by our DBA finally. I post this question because I can't totally understand the syntax above.

Comment: @underscore_d The sql updates `progress` with value `0` instead of `5`, but `semester_id` is not affected

Comment: [misread originally] I guess it's implicitly converting everything after the 1st `=` to a single boolean expression containing 2 logical `and`s, or something like that. That's odd and should at least warn, though. If so, this is why other languages mercifully differentiate between assigning and comparing `=`s.

Answer (score 3):

What your code does is this

```
update table set progress = (5 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4);
```

The expression:

```
5 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4
```

is evaluated as `0` in your case because it consists of *Boolean* statements that are evaluated as `0` for `False` and `1` for True.
If you want to update multiple columns you don't use the `AND` operator but commas between the columns:

```
update table 
set progress = 5, id = 176, semester_id = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help at all...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(progress INT NOT NULL
,id INT NOT NULL
,semester_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(3,176,4),
(4,176,5),
(5,177,4),
(6,178,3);

SELECT progress = 5 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4 FROM my_table;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| progress = 5 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             0 |
|                                             0 |
|                                             0 |
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+

SELECT progress = 3 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4 FROM my_table;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| progress = 3 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             1 |
|                                             0 |
|                                             0 |
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

?

Comment: No it does not help because it does not explain anything. It outputs the result that the OP already has.

Comment: This is very illustrative but would still benefit from a little more narrative. +1 anyway

Comment: @Strawberry When I saw the answer for the first time, I understand what `progress = 3 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4` means. It's a valid expression. Both of your answers are helpful.

Comment: SELECT progress = 3 and id = 176 and semester_id = 4 FROM my_table;   in this select statement is cosideres as the boolean expression if all's values are matched then it return TRUE (1) else FALSE(0).